# MongoDB one to many design challenges with nested documents

Tags: mongodb, database-schema, data-modeling

What would be the best way to design schema for a User Settings REST api on top of mongodb.

I am from a Relational background. The problem is to transe a Relational data model to document or nosql data model.

The **Use cases** which my api's should serve is as below:

1. Create a setting for a user
2. Update a setting for a user
3. read a setting for user
4. delete a setting for a user

A User can be associated with multiple Applications. Each Application can have multiple Settings. I have read about one to many relationship from the mongodb documentation but did not get the feel of how to design.

The current designs i am considering are as below

## **Design 1:**

**User Document:**

```
{
  "userid":"r8142r",
  "usertype":"admin",
  "applications":[application1Reference,application2Reference....]
}
```

**Application Document:**

```
{
  "applicationid":"application1Reference",
  "applicationSettings":[settings1Reference,settings2Reference...]
}
```

**Settings Document:**

```
{
  "settingid":"setting1Reference",
   "settingkey":"refreshTime",
   "settingValue":"20mins",
   "isActive":"yes",
   "updatedOn":"2017-06-22"
}
```

**Design 2:**

```
{
  "userid":"12345",
  "applicationID":[app1Ref,app2Ref],
  "settingKey":"refreshInterval",
  "settingValue":"20min",
  "groupName":"xgroup",
  "isActive":"yes",
  "uploadedOn":"2017-06-22"
}
```

The Design 1 looks like more of a relational way of design. The second design looks like a makeshift design because it does not serve my use cases.Is there any other way to design the documents.

I would like to know if this is the scale-able design. Can my DB Design cater to all usecases. What can be the issues.

Answer (score 1):

When I first jump in to **no-sql database**, I faced similar issue. I always try to design more relational schemas. But if you want to have full benefit of no-sql database, your design should be more document oriented, i.e. documents need to be saved hierarchically and all the required data needs to be stored in **single document** instead of multiple document or storing them in different tables with referential constraints as in SQL. That is why **MongoDB** does not support any **joins** or **foreign key** constraints or **transaction**. Also, this make MongoDB more scalable.

According to your use-case requirements, since each user can have multiple applications and each application may have multiple settings, and `User -> Application -> Settings` have `one -> many` relationship, you can embedded each application settings data to user document as below:

```
{
    //.. personal details
    "applications": [
        {
            "app_id":"12345",
            "name":"application_1",
            "settings": [
                {
                    "settingid":"1",
                    "settingkey":"refreshTime",
                    "settingValue":"20mins",
                    "isActive":"yes",
                    "updatedOn":"2017-06-22"
                },
                {
                    "settingid":"2",
                    "settingkey":"refreshTime",
                    "settingValue":"10mins",
                    "isActive":"no",
                    "updatedOn":"2017-06-22"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "app_id":"8999",
            "name":"application_12",
            "settings": [
                {
                    "settingid":"1",
                    "settingkey":"refreshTime",
                    "settingValue":"20mins",
                    "isActive":"yes",
                    "updatedOn":"2017-06-22"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```